# mysql вывести дочерние записи

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `text` TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

нужно запросом, отобразить только вложенные записи по id родителя

```
 - 1 Текст (id = 254357, pid = 0, tid = 254357)
 - - 1.1 Текст (id = 254362, pid = 254357, tid = 254357)
 - - - 1.1.1 Текст (id = 254363, pid = 254362, tid = 254357)
 - - - - 1.1.2 Текст (id = 254369, pid = 254363, tid = 254357)
 - - 1.2 Текст (id = 254359, pid = 254357, tid = 254357)
 - - - 1.2.1 (id = 254360, pid = 254359, tid = 254357)
```

Например, при использовании id = 254362, вывести родитель и его дочерние записи 254363 и 254369, можно ли реализовать такой запрос, не прибегая к постобработке скриптами?

Comment: Если известно, сколько дочерних уровней надо - то можно сделать. Если потенциально дочерних уровней бесконечное кол-во, то одним запросом нельзя.

Comment: а чем вас "постобработка скриптами" не устраивает?  можно завести отдельную таблицу, в которой будете хранить связь между родительской категорией и всеми ее детьми. Тогда от поля tid можно будет избавиться, а все дочерние записи можно будет выбрать одним запросом. Только в коде программы все равно придется приводить к нужному виду. К тому же - можно сделать автоподгрузку нужных записей. Т.е. показываете сначала родительские записи, а рядом с ними "плюсик". Нажали его - подгрузились прямые дети этой записи, у каждой так же "плюсик". Нажали его у ребенка - подгрузились дети ребенка и т.д.

Comment: BOPOH, в имеющемся запросе сортировка идет по полю time, что затрудняет вести отдельные данные в нужном порядке, чтобы в след. цикле их отсеивать, поэтому, хотелось бы узнать, как на простом примере это сделать в связке php + mysql.

Comment: @aliokero Можно, 2я вызовами. Из которого первый - вызов хранимой процедуры, которая наполнит временную таблицу нужными id с указанием путей до них. А вторым запросом select который из этой временной таблицы уже выберет данные. Ну либо процедура может вернуть сразу набор, но там внутри нее придется городить всякие списки

Comment: @Mike 
`SELECT group_concat(lv separator ',') AS id
FROM
  (SELECT @pv:=
     (SELECT group_concat(id separator ',')
      FROM entries
      WHERE pid IN (@pv)) AS lv
   FROM entries
   JOIN
     (SELECT @pv:= 253108) tmp
   WHERE pid IN (@pv)) a`

сделал так, потом во втором запросе с помощью WHERE id IN (первый запрос) выбираю нужные данные, но мой первый запрос не находит все дочерние ID...

Comment: @aliokero Не будет mysql делать это рекурсивно, сколько уровней в запросе написать, столько и выберет, а рисовать этажерку из 10 select from select сложно и главное, не универсально, до 11 уровня не доберется. Только хранимая процедура в цикле накапливающая данные.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот если добавить поле path, в которое положить ровно то, что написано при выводе (`1.1.1`), то все делается одним запросом.

Только вместо единичек должно быть id. То есть,

- для ид 254362 путь будет '254357'
- для ид 254363 путь будет '254357.254362'
- для ид 254369 путь будет '254357.254362.254363'

и так далее.

сортируем, соответственно, по tid, path, id

Этот подход называется Materialized Path. Ещё получить одним запросом сразу отсортированные данные позволяет Nested Sets, но мне никогда не хватало терпения в нем разобраться.

Но гоняться за "одним запросом", как выше замечено, смысла немного. Получить не сортированные данные одним запросом и отсортировать в скрипте - абсолютно не проблема. Возражение вида

> в имеющемся запросе сортировка идет по полю time, что затрудняет вести
>   отдельные данные в нужном порядке, чтобы в след. цикле их отсеивать,
>   поэтому, хотелось бы узнать, как на простом примере это сделать в
>   связке php + mysql

я не понял, для меня оно звучит как "Что использовать чтобы огурцы ложкой банка майонеза."